# Go 1.6 does not work on OS X Yosemite

Tags: go, homebrew, osx-yosemite

OS X Yosemite with all patches. Installed go with

```
brew install go --cross-compile-common
```

Created ~/work, setup environments like this:

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/work
export GOROOT='/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6'
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

Now attempt to add a package gives me an error:

```
go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc

package archive/zip: unrecognized import path "archive/zip" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package bytes: unrecognized import path "bytes" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package encoding/json: unrecognized import path "encoding/json" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package encoding/xml: unrecognized import path "encoding/xml" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package errors: unrecognized import path "errors" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package expvar: unrecognized import path "expvar" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package flag: unrecognized import path "flag" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package fmt: unrecognized import path "fmt" (import path does not begin with hostname)
...
```

Does Go support OS X 10.10?
What did I miss here?

Comment: Why downvote on this question?

Comment: Unset your GOROOT. Homebrew will manage this for you during installation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to set your `GOROOT` to `/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6/libexec`. I remember I had the same problem and this fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to set the `GOROOT` variable anymore http://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/14/you-dont-need-to-set-goroot-really

Answer (score 2):

> Does Go support OS X 10.10?

Yes, for Go up to 1.12.
Starting Q4 2019, not anymore. See [Go 1.12 doc](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.12#darwin):

> ### Darwin
>
> **Go 1.12 is the last release that will run on macOS 10.10 Yosemite**.
>
> **Go 1.13 (Q4 2019) will require macOS 10.11 El Capitan or later**.
>
> `libSystem` is now used when making syscalls on Darwin, ensuring forward-compatibility with future versions of macOS and iOS.
> The switch to `libSystem` triggered additional App Store checks for private API usage.
> Since it is considered private, `syscall.Getdirentries` now always fails with `ENOSYS` on iOS.